# "Проверка в торгово-розничных сетей" — как назвать допущенную здесь ошибку?

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

"Проверка в торгово-розничных **сетей**". Речевая ошибка или нет? Как назвать такую ошибку? Неправильное употребление падежной формы существительного? Или изменение падеждного окончания существительного?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь *грамматическая* ошибка (ошибка в падежном окончании существительного множественного числа в предложном падеже). Возможно либо "в торгово-розничных сет**ях**" (проверка где?), либо без предлога, в родительном падеже: "торгово-розничных сетей" (проверка чего?).

Comment: Это грамматическая ошибка - нарушение управления